# Possible to bold specific generated words with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, bold

Using this software called ShipStation that spits this out for a given item in an online order:

Zebra Striped Zubaz Pants
Size: Large
Color: Red

The HTML shortcode that generates this is [Item Options Without Replacement].

Since the software is limited in customization, I was wondering if there's a way to use CSS to bold specific parts of the text. If I wanted "Size:" or "Color:" to be bold, is there a way I could use CSS if I can wrap the shortcode in a class?

Comment: What is the specific HTML this shortcode generates? Can you look that up? That might help. Otherwise you'd have to use Javascript for this purpose.

Comment: Well i don't know about ShipStation but i believe it runs in a browser. if so then you need to inspect the specific content you want to be bold. Look out for the container element of that content and look for any class already attached to it. after that, you can apply bold property in that class and make it Important.

Comment: looks like a generated list ... https://help.shipstation.ca/hc/en-ca/articles/360045863191-How-do-I-display-item-options-as-a-list-  ? from here you have ul & li & nth-chid(n) options . (see to "view source" of your page to know what you really have there.)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Are you saying it is or is not possible?

Comment: nop/yes, i say your code seems to generate a list (ul / li) , which can be styled individually. Take a look at the source of your page to find out the HTML structure generated . (most of browser have this option on right click then show source code). From there you can find out your CSS selector

Answer (score -1):

```js
var text = `
  Zebra Striped Zubaz Pants
  Size: Large
  Color: Red
`

const el = document.getElementById('text');
text = text.replace('Size', '<span class="bold">Size</span>')
text = text.replace('Color', '<span class="bold">Color</span>')
el.innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.text .bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<pre id="text" class="text">
  
</pre>
```

It is not possible to achieve what you are asking for, You have to modify the text to add some DOM through javascript and apply styling around the DOM.

Comment: It's necessary to know the generated HTML code to judge whether it's possible or not, which the OP didn't post. If the generated HTML contains tags for those terms (for example `span`s that might even have a particular class), it *is* possible.

Comment: i am answering based on the question that is asked and it did not mention the any DOM, if the DOM is not present then my answer is right, if the DOM is present than it should be mentioned in the question.

Comment: the op did not give enough details, but you can yourself find out the HTML produced : https://help.shipstation.ca/hc/en-ca/articles/360045863191-How-do-I-display-item-options-as-a-list- ... it's a list , no span